# Restructuring program to use asyncio

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, network-programming, pygame

Currently I have a game that does networking synchronously using the `socket` module.

It is structured like this:

Server:

```
while True:
    add_new_clients()
    process_game_state()
    for client in clients:
        send_data(client)
        get_data_from(client)
```

Client:

```
connect_to_server()
while True:
    get_data_from_server()
    process_game_state()
    draw_to_screen()
    send_input_to_server()
```

I want to replace the network code with some that uses a higher level module than `socket`, e.g. `asyncio` or gevent. However, I don't know how to do this.

All the examples I have seen are structured like this:

```
class Server:
    def handle_client(self, connection):
        while True:
            input = get_input(connection)
            output = process(input)
            send(connection, output)
```

and then `handle_client` being called in parallel, using threads or something, for each client that joins.

This works fine if the clients can be handled separately. However, I still want to keep a game-loop type structure, where processing only occurs in one case - I don't want have to check collisions etc. for each client. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you understand how to create a server using a protocol and how asynchronous paradigm work.

All you need is **to break down** your while event loop into **handlers**.

Let's see server case and client case :

## Server case

#### A client (server-side)

You need to create a what we call a protocol, it will be used to create the server and serve as a pattern where each instance = a client :

```
class ClientProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        # Here, we have a new player, the transport represent a socket.
        self.transport = transport


    def data_received(self, data):
        packet = decode_packet(data) # some function for reading packets
        if packet.opcode == CMSG_MOVE: # opcode is a operation code.
            self.player.move(packet[0]) # packet[0] is the first "real" data.
            self.transport.write("OK YOUR MOVE IS ACCEPTED") # Send back confirmation or whatever.
```

Ok, now you have a idea of how you can do thing with your clients.

#### Game state

After that, you need to process your game state each X ms :

```
def processGameState():
    # some code...
    eventLoop.call_later(0.1, processGameState) # every 100 ms, processGameState is called.
```

At some point, you will call processGameState in your initialization and it will tell the eventLoop to call processGameState 100 ms later (**It may not be the ideal way to do it, but it's an idea like another one**)

As for sending new data to clients, you just need to store a list of `ClientProtocol` and write to their transport with a simple for each.

The get_data_from is obviously removed, as we receive all our data asynchronously in the `data_received` method of the `ClientProtocol`.

This is a **sketch** of how you can refactor all your synchronous code into asynchronous code. You may want to add authentication, and some other things, if it's your first time with asynchronous paradigm, I suggest you to try to do it with Twisted more than asyncio : Twisted is likely to be more documented and explained everywhere than asyncio (but asyncio is quite the same as Twisted, so you can switch back everytime).

## Client case

It's pretty the same here.

But, you may need to pay attention to how you draw and how you manage your input. You may need to ultimately use another thread to call inputs handlers, and another thread to draw to the screen at a constant framerate.

## Conclusion

Think in asynchronous is pretty difficult at the start.

But it's worth the effort.

Note that even my approach may not be the best or adapted for games. I just feel I would do it like that, please, take your time to test your code and profile it.
Check if you don't **mix synchronous and asynchronous** code in the same function without proper handling using deferToThread (or other helpers), it would **destroy** your game's **performances**.